# How to check if a Google Books item is in the public domain without API?

Tags: copyright, google-books

I know the Google Books API, but if for whatever reason I can't access it, how do I check whether a book is in the [public domain](http://publicdomainday.org/)?

For whatever reason, Google doesn't think this is an information worth of the information pages or of the advanced book search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google doesn't guarantee copyright status etc. etc., but in the HTML of the book description you can find a lot of information enclosed in a script tag, for example:

```
<script>_OC_addFlags(... {"volume_id":"qyi8-5g8dzAC","is_ebook":true,"volumeresult": ... ,"sample_url": ... ,"is_browsable":true,"is_public_domain":true}, ...);</script>
```

Checking for `is_public_domain` should be ok.

Of course you're really supposed to use the API, [in the example](https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/qyi8-5g8dzAC):

`"accessInfo": {
  "country": "IT",
  "viewability": "ALL_PAGES",
  "embeddable": true,
  "publicDomain": true,
  "textToSpeechPermission": "ALLOWED",
  "epub": {
   "isAvailable": false
  },`